# Setting Static Field in Non-static Constructor | Why does this work? | C#

Tags: c#, logging, static-methods

In this application, we are using [JUST.net](https://github.com/WorkMaze/JUST.net) with custom functions. Custom functions in JUST.net must be static methods. I created a class that defines all static functions; these functions are registered to the JUST.net context via reflection. I need to include logging in these static functions in case one of the mappings fails.

To accomplish this, we have code like this:

```
public class Transformations
{
  private static ILogger<Transformation> _logger;

  public Transformations(ILogger<Transformations> logger)
  {
     _logger = logger;
  }

  public static string MapAddress(string? streetNumber, string? streetName)
  {
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(streetNumber)
    { 
      _logger.LogError("The property was not provided.");
    }
    // etc...
  }
  // etc...
}
```

When I call it from my tests, the logger works if I instantiate the class and reference the functions statically. If I do not instantiate the class and reference the methods statically, the logger does not work.

I.e.:

```
  public class AddressUnitTest
  {
    private readonly Transformations _transformations;

    public AddressUnitTest()
    {
      var serilog = new LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.Console().CreateLogger();
      var loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory().AddSerilog(serilog);
      var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Transformations>();
      _transformations = new Transformations(logger);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Address(string? streetNumber, string? streetName)
    {
      var actualValue = Transformations.MapAddress(streetNumber, streetName);
      // etc...
    }
  }
```

Given you cannot use `_transformations.MapAddress()` and must reference the methods statically, i.e.: `Transformation.MapAddress()`, why does the logger work when I instantiate a seemingly unrelated version of it?

That is, why does setting `_transformations = new Transformations(logger);` give `Transformations.MapAddress()` access to the logger?

It seems to work; I just don't understand why. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Well you wrote it yourself in this strange way. `_logger` field is static, and you assign this static field in instance constructor. Static methods of course have access to static fields, so not quite clear where the confusion comes from. Of course this approach is not good - just remove constructor and use something like `public static SetLogger(ILogger ...)` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is that the only time that the `_logger` field is initialised to anything is in the class constructor.

It would be better to write a static method to initialise the logger, and make your entire class static (so that all its members must be static) so that this confusion doesn't arise:

```
public static class Transformations
{
  private static ILogger<Transformation> _logger;

  public static void InitialiseLogger(ILogger<Transformations> logger)
  {
     _logger = logger;
  }

  public static string MapAddress(string? streetNumber, string? streetName)
  {
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(streetNumber)
    { 
      _logger.LogError("The property was not provided.");
    }
    // etc...
  }
  // etc...
}
```

In your unit tests, it should be possible to have a startup method which calls `Transformations.InitialiseLogger()` just once for all the unit tests, so you don't have to repeat it in each test method. (Or some other way - I'm not familiar with how xUnit does this.)